# How can i solve this error with Pytorch summary?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to load a DNN pytorch model using:

```
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class myDNN(nn.Module):  
  def __init__(self):
    super(myDNN, self).__init__()

    # layers definition

    # first convolutional block
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=2, out_channels=8, kernel_size=7) 
    self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size = 2, stride=2) 

    # second convolutional block
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=8, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3) 
    self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size = 2, stride=2) 

    # third convolutional block
    self.conv3 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3) 
    self.pool3 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size = 2, stride=2) 

    # fourth convolutional block
    self.conv4 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3) 
    self.pool4 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size = 2, stride=2) 

    # fifth convolutional block
    self.conv5 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3) 
    self.pool5 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size = 2, stride=2) 

    
    self.flatten = nn.Flatten() 
    self.drop1 = nn.Dropout(p=0.5) 
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=3200, out_features=50) #3200 is a random number, 
    probably wrong
    self.drop2 = nn.Dropout(p=0.5) #dropout 
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=50, out_features=25)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(in_features=25, out_features=2)


  def forward(self, x, y):  
    x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))  
    x = self.pool1(x)
    x = F.relu(self.conv2(x)) 
    x = self.pool2(x)
    x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
    x = self.pool3(x)
    x = F.relu(self.conv4(x))
    x = self.pool3(x)
    x = F.relu(self.conv5(x))
    x = self.pool5(x)
    
    y = F.relu(self.conv1(y))  
    y = self.pool1(y)
    y = F.relu(self.conv2(y)) 
    y = self.pool2(y)
    y = F.relu(self.conv3(y))
    y = self.pool3(y)
    y = F.relu(self.conv4(y))
    y = self.pool3(y)
    y = F.relu(self.conv5(y))
    y = self.pool5(y)

    #flatten
    x = self.flatten(x)
    y = self.flatten(y)

    w = torch.cat(x,y,1) 
    
    w = self.drop1(w) #dropout layer
    w = F.relu(self.fc1(w)) #layer fully connected with re lu
    w = self.drop2(w)
    w = F.relu(self.fc2(w)) #layer fully connected with re lu 

    w = self.fc3(w) #layer fully connected
    out = F.log_softmax(w, dim=1) 

    return out
```

The DNN that i am trying to reproduce is the one mentioned in this paper:

https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2399-6528/aa83fa/pdf

I am not sure that it's correct, anyway, when I load Pytorch's summary function:

```
model = myDNN()
print(model)

from torchsummary import summary
if torch.cuda.is_available():
  summary(model.cuda(), input_size = [(1,892),(1,492)])
else:
  summary(model, input_size = [(1,892),(1,492)])
```

but i get this error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-123-6846b44c144c> in <module>()
      6 from torchsummary import summary
      7 if torch.cuda.is_available():
----> 8   summary(model.cuda(), input_size = [(1,892),(1,492)]) 
      9 else:
     10   summary(model, input_size = [(1,892),(1,492)])

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    297                             _single(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
    298         return F.conv1d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
--> 299                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    300 
    301     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:

RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [8, 2, 7], expected input[2, 1, 892] to have 2 channels, but got 1 channels instead
```

Please any help would be grateful, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first layer of the model expects two channels rather than one.
Simply pass the correct input shape to "summary" as follows:

```
summary(model, ((2, dim1),(2,dim2))
```

Edit: In the forward function I would do the concatenation as follows (if both model's inputs have the same shape):

```
w = torch.cat([x,y], dim=1)
w = self.flatten(w)
```

---

Edit:
Here is a working code using the correct implementation

```
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch

class myDNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(myDNN, self).__init__()

    # layers definition

    # first convolutional block
    self.path1_conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=2, out_channels=8, kernel_size=7)
    self.path1_pool1 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size = 2, stride=2)

    # second convolutional block
    self.path1_conv2 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=8, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3)
    self.path1_pool2 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size = 2, stride=2)

    # third convolutional block
    self.path1_conv3 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3)
    self.path1_pool3 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size = 2, stride=2)

    # fourth convolutional block
    self.path1_conv4 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3)
    self.path1_pool4 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size = 2, stride=2)

    # fifth convolutional block
    self.path1_conv5 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3)
    self.path1_pool5 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size = 2, stride=2)

    self.path2_conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=2, out_channels=8, kernel_size=7)
    self.path2_pool1 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size = 2, stride=2)

    # second convolutional block
    self.path2_conv2 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=8, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3)
    self.path2_pool2 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size = 2, stride=2)

    # third convolutional block
    self.path2_conv3 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3)
    self.path2_pool3 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size = 2, stride=2)

    # fourth convolutional block
    self.path2_conv4 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3)
    self.path2_pool4 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size = 2, stride=2)

    # fifth convolutional block
    self.path2_conv5 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3)
    self.path2_pool5 = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size = 2, stride=2)


    self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
    self.drop1 = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=50) #3200 is a random number,probably wrong
    self.drop2 = nn.Dropout(p=0.5) #dropout
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=50, out_features=25)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(in_features=25, out_features=2)


  def forward(self, x, y):
    x = F.relu(self.path1_conv1(x))
    x = self.path1_pool1(x)
    x = F.relu(self.path1_conv2(x))
    x = self.path1_pool2(x)
    x = F.relu(self.path1_conv3(x))
    x = self.path1_pool3(x)
    x = F.relu(self.path1_conv4(x))
    x = self.path1_pool3(x)
    x = F.relu(self.path1_conv5(x))
    x = self.path1_pool5(x)

    y = F.relu(self.path2_conv1(y))
    y = self.path2_pool1(y)
    y = F.relu(self.path2_conv2(y))
    y = self.path2_pool2(y)
    y = F.relu(self.path2_conv3(y))
    y = self.path2_pool3(y)
    y = F.relu(self.path2_conv4(y))
    y = self.path2_pool3(y)
    y = F.relu(self.path2_conv5(y))
    y = self.path2_pool5(y)

    #flatten
    x = self.flatten(x)
    y = self.flatten(y)

    w = torch.cat([x,y],dim=1)
    print(w.shape)
    w = self.drop1(w) #dropout layer
    w = F.relu(self.fc1(w)) #layer fully connected with re lu
    w = self.drop2(w)
    w = F.relu(self.fc2(w)) #layer fully connected with re lu

    w = self.fc3(w) #layer fully connected
    out = F.log_softmax(w, dim=1)

    return out

def main():
    model = myDNN()
    print(model)
    from torchsummary import summary
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        summary(model.cuda(), input_size = [(2,246),(2,447)])
    else:
        summary(model, input_size = [(2,246),(2,447)])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why (2, 1892, 1492)? I have two Pytorch tensors that correspond to two numpy arrays once with shape 19000,1,892 and once with shape 19000,1,492.

Comment: I also think that the correct implementation should have differen paths so all the layers but the dense layers should be different.

Comment: Now i have this error:


rand(): argument 'size' must be tuple of ints, but found element of type tuple at pos 2

Also are you saying that when I define the layers I should define two identical layers for each layer?

Comment: @Nexus I have updated my answer with a working code with the correct input shapes even for the first dense layer. Please mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, before i have just another question:


I am trying to see if thing work with this code

Comment: feat_z, label = next(iter(tr_Z_dataloader))

feat_phi, label = next(iter(tr_Phi_dataloader))

feat_z=feat_z.to(device) 

feat_phi=feat_phi.to(device)

label=label.to(device)

out = model(feat_z.view(batch_size,-1),feat_phi.view(batch_size,-1)) 

print(out.shape) 

print(out[0])

Comment: and i get this error:
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [8, 2, 7], expected input[1, 100, 894] to have 2 channels, but got 100 channels instead

Comment: tr_Z_dataloader and tr_Phi_dataloader are made with numpy array with shape (197178, 2, 447) , (197178,) and (197178, 2, 246),(197178,) converted to torch tensors

Comment: Could you provide that part of the code that gives the error? The part where you create the data and data loader.

Comment: `tr_Z = tr_Z.astype('float32')
tr_Phi = tr_Phi.astype('float32')
tr_target = tr_target.astype('float32')

print(tr_Z.shape)
print(tr_Phi.shape)
print(tr_target.shape)`


With shape 
(197178, 2, 447)
(197178, 2, 246)
(197178,)

Comment: `tr_Z = torch.tensor(tr_Z)
tr_Phi = torch.tensor(tr_Phi)
tr_target = torch.tensor(tr_target)


from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset

tr_Z_Dataset = TensorDataset(tr_Z,tr_target)
tr_Phi_Dataset = TensorDataset(tr_Phi,tr_target)



from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
torch.manual_seed(101)

batch_size = 100

tr_Z_dataloader = DataLoader(
    tr_Z_Dataset,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    drop_last=True
)

tr_Phi_dataloader = DataLoader(
    tr_Phi_Dataset,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    drop_last=True
) `

Comment: `x, y = next(iter(tr_Z_dataloader))
u, v = next(iter(tr_Phi_dataloader))

print("Z features shape:", x.shape)
print("Target shape:", y.shape)
print("Phi features shape:", u.shape)`

Z features shape: torch.Size([100, 2, 447])
Target shape: torch.Size([100])
Phi features shape: torch.Size([100, 2, 246])

Comment: Could please provide the creation of tr_Z and tr_Phi  with numpy?

Comment: If you want this is colab link

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_0GZcD_FXX6B8fcgrvg_BXxLo2kO1_Md?usp=sharing

Comment: `tr_Z = []
for i in range(tr_innerZ.shape[0]):
  tr_Z.append(np.vstack([tr_innerZ[i], tr_outerZ[i]]))
tr_Z = np.array(tr_Z)
print(tr_Z.shape)`

And tr_Phi in a similar way

Comment: tr_innerZ and tr_outerZ are created from datas

Comment: So you can just pass the inputs as is without changing the view 

```
model(feat_z,feat_phi)
```

Comment: Thanks, i have other problems, you can see it clearer on colab.
When i try to train my DNN i receive this error:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

I only tried to modify my professor code, but it's so difficults with two inputs, i have never seen a thing like that before

Comment: If you want, i would like to contact you on other way, just to avoid infinite discussion in the comment

Comment: I think you could maybe read this [link] (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html) and try a bit first and then ask another question. Check what are the inputs to the loss function and how the enumeration over the data loader is done. Also, remember during training, you have two inputs tensors, one tensor as output, and one tensor as a label.

Comment: I tried multiple times. I modified code, now seems to run but it goes under an infinite cycle and where it's printed only: torch.Size([100, 2048])

Comment: You still need 5 reputation points to initiate a StackOverflow chat. How or where do you want to chat?